# Get the last Docker image built

Tags: docker

This command gives a list of image and container IDs ordered from top to bottom by last build time:

```
docker images
```

All my docker images are appended with the hash git head commit.

The results

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
username/play-table-of-contents-1474f94    latest              6141b8177c2f        34 minutes ago      149MB
username/play-table-of-contents-2616f5f    latest              2b5422dd91ba        About an hour ago   149MB
```

Is there a way to get only the last image by name ? ( ie: case 6141b8177c2f )

I tried with

```
docker images --format "{{.Names}}"
```

My end goal is to run the last docker image built. To do this, I need to

1. get the last image name in bash script variable.
2. `docker run ... $last_image ...`

Comment: Note that the command `docker images` (or `docker image ls`) does not give you a "a list of images and container ids".  It gives you a list of image names and image ids.  The `docker ps` (or `docker container ls`) command gives you information about containers.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Agreed with @larsks that you might be mixing up images with containers. What do you mean by "extract?"

Comment: @larsks , brandon-barnett , you're right . I used the wrong word for image and container. I re-edited

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Docker command `docker images` **list out most recently created images**.

The following command list out **the first image from the above list**. I believe you are looking for this command.

```
docker images | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR==2'
```

You would probably deploy a container of the image from above command

```
docker run $(docker images | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR==2')
```

Comment: Thanks , exactly what I was looking for `awk '{print $1}'` prints the last repository . But you could have built images from the same docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) . I'd go to find the Image ID `awk '{print $3}'` . EDIT : I changed my repository naming convention

Comment: Combining the two answers here: `docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | head -1` that'll give you the Image ID of the most recent image.

Answer (score 10):

All the other answers' solution relies on the fact *docker image sorts the output by date already*. This may not be true. A **consistent solution** would be to sort them by the creation date and get the latest one. I used the following command, this is consistent.

```
docker images --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedAt}}" | sort -rk 2 | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

This command sorts the output of the docker images command by `CreatedAt` column and print the id of the latest image

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer**

```
docker run ... $(docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}" | head -1) ...
```

`docker ps -a` return the stopped and running containers in the order "Last to First".

Answer (score 4):

**Powershell**

```
docker images --format "{{.ID}}" | select -first 1
```

example use with docker run:

```
docker run -it (docker images --format "{{.ID}}" | select -first 1)
```

**Bash**

```
docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | head -1
```

example use with docker run:

```
docker run -it $(docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | head -1)
```

Answer (score 4):

This returns the `IMAGEID` of the latest built docker image:

```
docker images -q --format='{{.ID}}' | head -1
```

You can even collect it in a variable and use it as you like:

```
IMAGE_ID=$(docker images -q --format='{{.ID}}' | head -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter the last docker image you ran :

```
docker run -it $(docker images | awk '{print $3}' | awk 'NR==2') /bin/sh
```

OR

```
docker run -it $(docker images | awk '{print $3}' | awk 'NR==2') bash
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need get last build from an specific image name.. you can do:

```
IMG_NAME="my-image-name"
IMG_LAST_BUILD=$(docker images | grep $IMG_NAME | awk 'NR==1{printf("%s\:%s",$1,$2)}')

echo $IMG_LAST_BUILD
#my-image-name:tag_version
```